# I'm working on wallpaper application and want to set wallpaper according to mobile screen size without croping Bitmap is not working for me

Tags: java, android

Want to set wallpaper by using wallpaper manager without cropping

```
         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy );

            WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance( getApplicationContext() );
            InputStream ins = null;
            try {
                ins = new URL( Imageurl ).openStream();
                wpm.setStream( ins );
                Toast.makeText( ImageViewerActivity.this, "wallpaper set successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

[orignal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAuvj.jpg)

[after setting it as wallpaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urIUN.jpg)

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: its croping wallpaper which i don't want. set full wallpaper according to resolution of screen.

Comment: well, how should it set 1000x1000 wallpaper on 1000x2000 screen for example? Also show how exactly it is cropping. Show the original image and screenshot of wallpaper

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAuvj.jpg orignal image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urIUN.jpg after setting it as wallpaper

Comment: it needs wider image for scrolling screens, right? Is it even possible to disable wallpaper scrolling?

Comment: Ok, themes like it is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127998/1568530

Comment: i don't want to scroll it . i need to set it as it is.

Comment: and that is exactly what I wrote about in last comment. Have you read it?

Comment: yes i read it but i don't know is it possible or not to stop scrolling .

Comment: the answer you have read is supposed to stop scrolling